# .Net Maui (XAML) Vertical GridView Layout D-Pad Navigation

Tags: android, xaml, maui

I am very new to Xamarin/.Net Maui development. I am working on a movie app (that's initially going to be targeted to Wide Screens). I am trying to create a Scrollable vertical grid view to show the list of movies similar to the layout below

[image]

I started with CollectionView  but I am nowhere close the the desired output. I would like to have Direction Key (D-Pad) support so that each individual item can be focused using D-Pad. Also each item in the grid needs to be click-able so that I can navigate to the Movie Details View. Also when the item is selected, I need to style that item differently (just like in the image, the selected item has a white background).

Here is what my current XAML looks like

```
    <CollectionView ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                    ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 6"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMovie, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding GetMovieDetailsCommand}"
                    SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={RelativeSource Self}}">                        
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image
                        AutomationId="ImageViewCell"
                        WidthRequest="500"
                        Source="{Binding PosterPath}" />
                    <StackLayout 
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                            AutomationId="LabelTitle"
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"
                            FontSize="10" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

and below is my output.

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone can guide me or provide me with a sample how to achieve this functionality so I can use D-Pad to navigate between the items and scroll vertically while selecting items.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you’ve tried and explain the specific problems you’re having with it

Comment: Please show some code (as text). What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: I have added the xaml and a screenshot of how it currently looks.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. What exactly are you struggling with? *(Quick reminder: This is not a coding service)*

Comment: @ewerspej please read the question... I am asking how can I support d-pad navigation in the above layout

Comment: Basically, `CollectionView` supports [item selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection) and comes with built-in scrolling. You shouldn't nest a `CollectionView` inside a `ScrollView`, though, [see here why](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview). You can respond to item selection events to open a detail view, as well. You're saying that you want d-pad navigation, but you're not being specific about it. So, what exactly is the issue? Is it the scrolling that doesn't work, is it the item selection?

Comment: Basically my application would not have touch support... It is intended to use on TV.... For example, if one item is focused and user clicks Down button on D-pad, I would like to focus on the item below... Similarly clicking right or left would focus on the items next to them..... The default behavior that I am seeing is when I click the down button, the entire layout scroll down rather than focusing the item below... Basically I am looking to do the navigation on items only using D-pad.... And only when user clicks the d-pad OK button than I would like to navigate to the detail screen

Comment: @Magik i am also looking for d-pad support in maui collection view? did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @JeevaSubburaj no I couldn't find any solution yet... Please do let me know if you find something

Comment: @Magik i am able to achieve this with onkeydown event. I will post the detailed answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

Officially, there is no Android TV D-Pad support from Maui.Net Application. Here is the the unofficial way to make it work.

Create Interface class (IPageKeyDown) class with the OnPageKeyDown Method.

```
  #if ANDROID
     using Android.Views;
    #endif
    namespace YourApp.Model
    {
        public interface IPageKeyDown
        {
           #if ANDROID       
              public bool OnPageKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e);    
           #endif
        }
    }
```

In your View Page where your collection view is rendered, add the following code.

First, Inherit the interface

```
public partial class ContentListPage : ContentPage<ContentViewModel>,IPageKeyDown
```

In the ContentListPage, implement the interface with all the key left, right, up, down and center event.

As part of key right event, increment the collection index by 1 from selected item. For key left event, decrement by 1 from the selected index. For up and down, increment by the no item in the row. Also, if we ever end up reaching to the max item count, reset the selected index to 0. Do not use onselecteditemchanged event as it will fire the event for every D-PAD move. Instead, wire up the center event and invoke the item selected logic to navigate to other page.

```
#if ANDROID
        public bool OnPageKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
            index = 0;
            switch (keyCode)
            {
                case Keycode.DpadUp:                   
                        ExecuteDpadUp();                
                    break;
                case Keycode.DpadDown:                   
                        ExecuteDpadDown();
                    break;
                case Keycode.DpadLeft:                   
                        ExecuteDpadLeft();                    
                    break;
                case Keycode.DpadRight:                  
                        ExecuteDpadRight();                    
                    break;
                case Keycode.DpadCenter:                    
                        ExecuteDpadCenter();
                        break;
                default: break;
            }              
            return false;
        }
    #endif

 public void ExecuteDpadDown()
    {
        index = Math.Min(Math.Max(BindingContext.ContentModels.IndexOf(BindingContext.SelectedContentModel) + BindingContext.DefaultNoOfColumn, 0), BindingContext.ContentModels.Count - 1);
        BindingContext.SelectedContentModel = BindingContext.ContentModels[index];
    }

    public void ExecuteDpadLeft()
    {
        index = Math.Min(Math.Max(BindingContext.ContentModels.IndexOf(BindingContext.SelectedContentModel) - 1, 0), BindingContext.ContentModels.Count - 1);
        BindingContext.SelectedContentModel = BindingContext.ContentModels[index];
    }

    public void ExecuteDpadRight()
    {
        index = Math.Min(Math.Max(BindingContext.ContentModels.IndexOf(BindingContext.SelectedContentModel) + 1, 0), BindingContext.ContentModels.Count - 1);
        BindingContext.SelectedContentModel = BindingContext.ContentModels[index];
    }

    public void ExecuteDpadCenter()
    {       
        OnItemSelected();        
    }
    
    private async void OnItemSelected()
{
    var contentModel = BindingContext.SelectedContentModel;
    if (contentModel != null)
    {
        var navigationParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var stream = await BindingContext.FetchStream(contentModel.Id);
        if (contentModel.TargetType == typeof(StreamPage))
        {
            navigationParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "stream", stream }
            };
        }           

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(contentModel.TargetType.Name, navigationParameters);
    }
}
```

To change the color while navigating in D-Pad, we need to apply Style Setter in Styles.Xaml

```
<Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="GridItemStyle">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                        Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>                        
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Finally, in MainActivity.cs under Platforms/Android folder, wire up the onkeydown event.

```
public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        Page p = Shell.Current.CurrentPage;

        if (p is IPageKeyDown)
        {
            bool handled =  (p as IPageKeyDown).OnPageKeyDown(keyCode, e);
            if (handled) return true;
        }

        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }
```